# Fill in missing values SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to fill in the column `[WTYPE]` WHERE NULL simply based on the column `[Session]`

```
| session | wtype  |
+---------+--------+
| ewrtewt | null   |
| ewrtewt | PRISPN |
| yuioplm | null   |
| yuioplm | LRISCO |
| ewrtewt | null   |
| tyuiolt | PRISPN |
| tyuiolt | null   |
```

So whereever there is a `WTYPE` I need to look at session value and make sure to copy the `WTYPE` to all that have the matching `SESSION`.

Comment: Can you have more than a single NON-NULL row for each session?

Comment: A windowed `MAX`/`MIN`?

Comment: Yes . each session is a unique number  , but my database has 4 rows for each session . .but only one of the rows has the correct WTYPE for that session . . but I need to fill out the entire column of WTYPE . .  e

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you would have made it clear if there could be multiple values per session (as we'd need to know which to choose) then you can use an updatable CTE like so:

```
with w as (
    select *, Max(wtype) over(partition by session) newwtype
    from t
)
update w
set wtype = newwtype
where wtype is null;
```

Comment: I updated my table to show that there can be multiple session values which share a WTYPE  . .hope this helps

Comment: This is still applicable to your sample data, does it work for you?

Comment: with w as (
    select *, Max(wtype) over(partition by session) as newwtype
    from WidgetLOG2
)
update w
set wtype = newwtype
where wtype is null;            (0 rows affected)

Comment: So what do you get with `select count(*) from WidgetLOG2 where wtype is null` ?

Comment: thanks that was the issue . . it was a zero length string . . . it works now !   thanks

Comment: Ok that's good to hear you have an answer that is working for you.